# How to create String with certain length and same value effectively in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I knew this can be achieved with for loop but I am looking for better solution.

```
createDummyString(1,'A') = 'A'
createDummyString(2.'A') = 'AA'
```

This will be used in hangman. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it like in the example below. To learn more about Strings read this: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/index.html

```
fun createDummyString(repeat : Int, alpha : Char) = alpha.toString().repeat(repeat)
```

---

Addendum:

If you want to make it more kotlinesque, you can also define `repeat` as extension function on `Char`

```
fun Char.repeat(count: Int): String = this.toString().repeat(count)
```

and call it like this:

```
'A'.repeat(1)
```

Comment: For anyone who just needs to create a String with a defined length without a function etc. you can use this:
(`"A".repeat(20)`) generates this: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Answer (score 6):

CharSequence has an extension method for this.

```
    fun CharSequence.repeat(n: Int): String // for any whole number
```

Example

```
    println("A".repeat(4))  // AAAA 
    println("A".repeat(0))  // nothing 
    println("A".repeat(-1)) // Exception
```

Reference : https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/repeat.html

I created a utility function using infix operator for this :

```
infix fun Int.times(s : CharSequence): CharSequence{
    return s.repeat(this)
}
//Use like val twoAs = 2 times "A"
println(a) // AA
```